# How to find id in MySQL column array

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, find-in-set

Company table structure:

```
(`id`=`1`, `name`=`CompanyName`, `members`=`3,52,134,21`)
```

The numbers in the `members` column are the user id's added to this company.

When user with `id = 3 OR 52 OR 134 OR 21` is logged in the row above should be returned with a MySQL query.

Is this possible with a query or do I have to edit my table structure?

Comment: Store id's as csv is very bad db design.You should think about normalization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE FIND_IN_SET('3',members);
```

**Note:** Never store data in comma separated format. If it is not late yet, then make one more table and normalize the structure. By normalizing the structure, it will be easy and fast searching by giving indexing to the column.

table name: `company_users`

```
pk_id    member_id   company_id(foriegn_key of company_table)
1          3           1
2          52          1
3          21          1
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you give an example?

Comment: @Koen example for what?

Comment: "If it is not late yet, then make one more table and normalize the structure. By normalizing the structure", Do you mean I have to make an extra table called "company_users" and link it with the company table?

Comment: @Koen yes, make 1 table that holds multiple entries of that comma separated ids..

Answer (score 3):

Use [**FIND_IN_SET()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

Try this:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM Company c
INNER JOIN company_users u ON FIND_IN_SET(u.id, c.members)
WHERE c.id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use FIND_IN_SET() method like this..

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE  FIND_IN_SET('your_search','table_column_name');
```

For example :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE FIND_IN_SET('52',members);
```